# How to get response from EventEmitter

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

I called one method from child.

In child component:

```
@Output() parentEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

click1() {
    //calling the method from child
    this.parentEvent.emit(myObj1);    
}
```

In parent component:

```
postMethod1(event) {
    //calling one post method(observable)
}
```

I need to call this `postMethod1()` method from child component. But the problem is that if any exception thrown in parent how can I handle this in child component? Cannot get the response from parent to child. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

To listen to the eventEmitted , all you have to do is :

`<child-component (parentEvent)='postMethod1($event)'></child-component>`

Now everytime an event is emitted by child component , `postMethod1()` is called and the data sent will be passed as parameter to the method .

**EDIT**

Since you want to handle the exception , you can use a shared service to notify the child component .

Suppose you have a `shared.service.ts`

In `shared.service.ts` ,you can do something like this :

`exception : Subject<String> = new Subject<String>();`

now you can create a method to send an exception from parent to child :

```
exceptionRaised(parentException : any){
 this.exception.next(parentException);
}
```

With this method , the exception can be subscribed in the child component like this :

in `child.component.ts`

```
_sharedService.exception.subscribe((exception : any) =>{
  //do whatever you want with the exception
});
```

To set the exception in parent , 
in `parent.component.ts` 
just call `_sharedService.exceptionRaised(yourException);`

Now your parent can communicate with child and notify if you have an exception

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to share any sample code/plunker?

Answer (score 1):

Say your child has the tag `app-child`. Then the correct syntax is :

```
<app-child (parentEvent)="postMethod1($event)"></app-child>
```

**EDIT** For your second issue, use a `ViewChild` in your parent component :

```
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;

  // Rest of your code

  postMethod1(event: any) {
    this.myService.makeHttpPost().subscribe(response => null, error => {
      this.child.handleError(error);
    });
  }
}
```

This will call the `handleError` in your child component.

Comment: Event is getting called. Problem is once this method called from child i need to write another post call in child component. If anything failed in postMethod1()  method. Another post call must stopped.